# How to make textbox enable and disable on change using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have piece of html code as well as script code. I need solution to handle on change event of one text box that disable act of inputting data in another text field. Could any one help me in regarding.

```
<div id="cca" class="leaf">
 <label class="control input text" title="">
    <span class="wrap">cca</span>
     <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]"/>
    <span class="warning"></span>
 </label>
</div>
<div id="ccit" class="leaf">
 <label class="control input text" title="">
    <span class="wrap">ccit</span>
     <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]"/>
    <span class="warning"></span>
 </label>
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    alert("hello");        
    $("#cca").on('change', 'label.control input', function (event) {
        alert('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
        $("ccit").prop('disabled',true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What isn't working? Could it be that you don't have a `<ccit></ccit>` element ?

Comment: Hi, this is my html code which i have written to make that script to perform action <div id="cca" class="leaf">
     <label class="control input text" title="">
        <span class="wrap">cca</span>
         <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]"/>
        <span class="warning"></span>
     </label>
</div>
<div id="ccit" class="leaf">
     <label class="control input text" title="">
        <span class="wrap">ccit</span>
         <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]"/>
        <span class="warning"></span>
     </label>
</div>

Comment: Now that you've posted the HTML, it should be `$("#ccit")`, hence my first comment

Comment: the `event.returnValue is deprecated. please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead` is just a warning on an old version of jQuery but it is not the reason your code is not working..  Javascript is a client side language so I don't understand what you mean by its not working server side.  Sorry I don't know how to help you at this point unless you can demonstrate exactly what is not working.

Comment: @ThotaPallavi try my `Update 2` that is the last thing I can think of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For one you were missing `#` on your `$("ccit")`

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    alert("hello");        
    $("#cca").change(function(){
        alert('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
        $("#ccit").prop('disabled',true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qS4RE/

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function () {               
    $("#cca").on('change', 'label.control input', function (event) {
        alert('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
        $("#ccit").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qS4RE/1/

**Update 2**

```
$(document).ready(function () {               
    $(document).on('change', '#cca label.control input', function (event) {
        alert('I am pretty sure the text box changed');
        $("#ccit").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: @ThotaPallavi Can I please get some feedback on my answer?  Did it help you?

Comment: Hi Trevor, That code which you have shared is working fine only when i specify id to that input text box. But in my case there is no id for input text box i was trying with your sample code with little changes $("#tan").prop('disabled',true).css('background-color', '#FF0033').css('color', '#FFFFFF');
      $("input:text").prop('disabled',true).css('background-color', '#FF0033').css('color', '#FFFFFF'); giving colors then i found in 1st statement which i have specified with #tan it is identifying label of that div and in 2nd statement if i specify input:text it is disabled for all text fields

Comment: Trevor, give me code by using my html code which is specified in question. It will be more helpful to me.

Comment: hey super Trevor. Thank you so much. You made my day. Its working fine.

Comment: @ThotaPallavi No problem please mark this answer as accepted.  Check the `checkmark` to the left of the question.  Thanks

Comment: Trevor, for disable action i have written code "$("#ccit").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);" but it is not getting enable. How to go about?

Comment: @ThotaPallavi That code seems to work. Your problem must be somewhere else in your function..  http://jsfiddle.net/qS4RE/2/

Comment: this is how i gave code, $("#cca").on('change', 'label.control input', function (event) {
     
     var txtcca=document.querySelector('#cca label.control input ').value;
     if(txtcca!=""){
      alert("1");
      $("#tan").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true).css('background-color', '#FF0033');
         event.preventDefault();
     }
     if(txtcca==""){
      alert("2");
      $("#tan").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
     }

Comment: hi that code which u have shared is working fine in client side but when i implement same code at server side that alert when on change is done that first alert itself not coming what to do? It throws an alert at console part like "event.returnValue is deprecated. please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: @ThotaPallavi that error comes from using an older version of jQuery 1.9.1 or lower.. But shouldn't affect the code.. I don't know what you mean by the code is not working at `server side`?  `jQuery` is a client side language...  I don't know how I can help at this point unless you can make a fiddle demonstrating the issue.. Or update  your question with the latest code.

Comment: ho ok Trevor. will change it to newer version of jQuery and try it. just now i have seen that it is using jquery-1.7.1.min.js.

Comment: Trevor, change is not working in 1.7.1.min.js but i would like to use that js file only and change option has to work how to go about

Comment: sorry for late reply Trevor. Update 2 is working fine.

Comment: Trevor could you please suggest me.... function checkValue(){
     var checkStr=document.querySelector('#tan label.control input ').value;
     alert(checkStr);
     //Regex obj = new Regex("[A-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-z]{1}");
     if(checkStr.match(/\b[A-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-z]{1}\b/)==null){
      alert("Please enter 5 alphabetic 4 numeric and 1 alphabet only in the field");
      return false;
     }else{
      alert("Correct..."+checkStr);
     }
    }how to use this code in jQuery by using onchange event only

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#ccit").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `attr` on the line  `$("ccit").attr('disabled',true);`

if `prop` gives you an error