# How to disable textbox from HTML disabled attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, spring, validation, controls

How to write jQuery code for disable textbox of HTML attributes.
By using jQuery I disabled the textbox based on userId, if `userId == ''` I want to enable the textbox if `userId != ''` I want to disabled the textbox.

```
<input type="text" value="${userJson.firstName}" class="txtcontrolwidth" name="firstName" maxlength="45" id="firstName"
       disabled="if(${userJson.userId} == '') {$('#firstName').attr('disabled', false)} else {$('#firstName').attr('disabled', true)}" />
```

Every time it is in disabled mode it is not enabled.

By calling outside function for disabling textbox it is easy.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(${userJson.userId} == "") {
    $('#firstName').attr('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('#firstName').attr('disabled', true);
}
</script>
```

But I want to disabled textbox in disabled attribute only.

Comment: You can't put Javascript inside the `disabled` attribute, you have to do it with a script in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: What is `${userJson.userId}`? That's not Javascript.

Comment: You should either use .attr("disabled", "disabled") or .prop("disabled", true).

Comment: check here [enable/disable textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665144/how-to-make-textbox-enable-and-disable-on-change-using-jquery)

Comment: @Esa it is not working.

Comment: @Barmar It is an expression language.

Comment: Does the expression language allow you to write `if` in it? You could put that into the expression language.

Answer (score 3):

First of all your html is bad! you can't write script inside the html without `<script></script>` tags.

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" value="" class="txtcontrolwidth" name="firstName" maxlength="45" id="firstName" />
```

**SCRIPT :**

```
$('#firstName').focusout(function(){

if( $(this).val() != "" ) {
    $(this).prop('disabled',true);
 } else {
    $(this).prop('disabled',false);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `disabled` attribute you are using in the `<input>` tag is a boolean attribute, but it is kind of tricky.

Check this out:

```
<!-- These will be disabled -->
<input type="text" disabled>    
<input type="text" disabled="true">
<input type="text" disabled="false">
<input type="text" disabled="myFunction()"> <!-- function will not be executed -->

<!-- And this will be enabled -->
<input type="text">
```

If you want your `<input>` to be enabled, do not include the `disabled` attribute in the tag.

Try replacing your code with this one:

```
<input type="text" value="${userJson.firstName}" class="txtcontrolwidth" name="firstName" maxlength="45" id="firstName" ${ userJson.userId == '' ? 'disabled' : '' } />
```

The code above will write `disabled` attribute to the tag only when `userJson.userId == ''`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="${userJson.firstName}" class="txtcontrolwidth" name="firstName" maxlength="45" id="firstName"
   disabled="if(${userJson.userId} == '') {$('#firstName').attr('disabled', false)} else {$('#firstName').attr('disabled', true)}" />
```

In the above code disabled attribute is present, so the textbox always in disabled mode, if javascript is returns true or false the disabled property value wont change.

use the following

```
<input type="text" value="${userJson.firstName}" class="txtcontrolwidth" name="firstName" maxlength="45" id="firstName" ${userJson.userId == ''?'': 'disabled'}>
```

if want to use a javascript function use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // you have to use double quotes around the value, because the ${userJson.userId} is evaluated then prints the value to the browser html, it cause javascript error
    if("${userJson.userId}" == "") {
        $('#firstName').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#firstName').prop(disabled', true);
}
</script>
```

Comment: `${userJson.userId == ''?'disabled': ''}` this logic is not working.

Comment: if **userJson.userId** contains empty spaces then the above logic won't work, before setting the value to **userJson.userId**, trim the value and try.

Comment: In this condition `${userJson.userId == ''?'disabled': ''}` we are checking  only for empty space. if we want to check for multiple values we can use `||` condition. try this in your code `${(userJson.userId == '' || userJson.userId =='1')?'':'disabled'}`